Is it really needed to change both G₂ points of the public & private witness vector in the Groth16’s trusted setup for avoiding public input forgery?
For those who don’t know about Groth16 :
By convention, public portions of the witness are the first $\ell$ elements of the vector $\mathbf{a}$. To make those elements public, the prover simply reveals them:
$$[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_\ell]$$
For the verifier to test that those values were in fact used, verifier must carry out some of the computation that the prover was originally doing.
Specifically, the prover computes:
$$\begin{align*}
[A]_1 &= [\alpha]_1 + \sum_{i=1}^m a_iu_i(\tau)\\
[B]_2 &= [\beta]_2 + \sum_{i=1}^m a_iv_i(\tau)\\
[C]_1 &= \sum_{i=\ell+1}^m a_i[\Psi_i]_1 + h(\tau)t(\tau)\\    
\end{align*}$$
Note that only the computation of $[C]_1$ changed -- the prover only uses the $a_i$ and $\Psi_i$ terms $\ell + 1$ to $m$.
The verifier computes the first $\ell$ terms of the sum:
$$[X]_1=\sum_{i=1}^\ell a_i\Psi_i$$
And the verification equation is:
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + [X]_1\bullet G_2 + [C]_1\bullet G_2$$
Part 2: Separating the public inputs from the private inputs with $\gamma$ and $\delta$
The first attack described in the tutorial I read and how it’s said to be prevented :
The assumption in the equation above is that the prover is only using $\Psi_{\ell+1}$ to $\Psi_m$ to compute $[C]_1$, but nothing stops a dishonest prover from using $\Psi_1$ to $\Psi_{\ell}$ to compute $[C]_1$, leading to a forged proof.
For example, here is our current verification equation:
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + \sum_{i=1}^\ell a_i\Psi_i +  [C]_1\bullet G_2$$
If we expand the C term under the hood, we get the following:
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + \sum_{i=1}^\ell a_i\Psi_i + \underbrace{(\sum_{i=\ell+1}^m a_i[\Psi_i]_1 + h(\tau)t(\tau))}_C \bullet G_2$$
Suppose for example and without loss of generality that $\mathbf{a} = [1,2,3,4,5]$ and $\ell=3$. In that case, the public part of the witness is $[1,2,3]$ and the private part is $[4,5]$.
The final equation would be as follows:
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + (1\Psi_1+2\Psi_2+3\Psi_3)\bullet G2 + \underbrace{(4\Psi_4 + 5\Psi_5  + h(\tau)t(\tau))}_C \bullet G_2$$
However, nothing stops the prover from creating an valid portion of the public witness as [1,2,0] and moving the zeroed out public portion to the private part of the computation as follows:
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + (1\Psi_1+2\Psi_2+\boxed{0\Psi_3})\bullet G2 + \underbrace{(\boxed{3\Psi_3}+4\Psi_4 + 5\Psi_5  + h(\tau)t(\tau))}_C \bullet G_2$$
The equation above is valid, but the witness does not necessarily satisfy the original constraints.
Therefore, we need to prevent the prover from using $\Psi_1$ to $\Psi_{\ell}$ as part of the computation of $[C]_1$.
Introducing $\gamma$ and $\delta$
To avoid the problem above, the trusted setup introduces new scalars $\gamma$ and $\delta$ to force $\Psi_{\ell+1}$ to $\Psi_m$ to be separate from $\Psi_1$ to $\Psi_{\ell}$. To do this, the trusted setup divides (multiplies by the modular inverse) the private terms (that constitute $[C]_1$) by $\delta$ and the public terms (that constitute $[X]_1$, the sum the verifier computes) by $\gamma$.
Since the $h(\tau)t(\tau)$ term is embedded in $[C]_1$, those terms also need to be divided by $\delta$.
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha,\beta,\tau,\gamma,\delta &\leftarrow \text{random scalars}\\
[\tau^{n-1}G_1,\tau^{n-2}G_1,\dots,\tau G_1,G_1] &\leftarrow \text{srs for } \mathbb{G}_1\\
[\tau^{n-1}G_2,\tau^{n-2}G_2,\dots,\tau G_2,G_2] &\leftarrow \text{srs for } \mathbb{G}_2\\
[\frac{\tau^{n-2}t(\tau)}{\delta},\frac{\tau^{n-3}t(\tau)}{\delta},\dots,\frac{\tau t(\tau)}{\delta},
\frac{t(\tau)}{\delta}] &\leftarrow \text{srs for }h(\tau)t(\tau)\\
\\
&\text{public portion of the witness}\\
[\Psi_1]_1 &= \frac{\alpha v_1(\tau) + \beta u_1(\tau) + w_1(\tau)}{\gamma}G_1\\
[\Psi_2]_1 &= \frac{\alpha v_2(\tau) + \beta u_2(\tau) + w_2(\tau)}{\gamma}G_1\\
&\vdots\\
[\Psi_\ell]_1 &= \frac{\alpha v_m(\tau) + \beta u_m(\tau) + w_m(\tau)}{\gamma}G_1\\
\\
&\text{private portion of the witness}\\
[\Psi_{\ell+1}]_1 &= \frac{\alpha v_{\ell+1}(\tau) + \beta u_{\ell+1}(\tau) + w_{\ell+1}(\tau)}{\delta}G_1\\
[\Psi_{\ell+2}]_1 &= \frac{\alpha v_{\ell+2}(\tau) + \beta u_{\ell+2}(\tau) + w_{\ell+2}(\tau)}{\delta}G_1\\
&\vdots\\
[\Psi_{m}]_1 &= \frac{\alpha v_{m}(\tau) + \beta u_{m}(\tau) + w_{m}(\tau)}{\delta}G_1\\
\end{align*}$$
The trusted setup publishes
$$([\alpha]_1,[\beta]_2,[\gamma]_2,[\delta]_2,\text{srs}_{G_1},\text{srs}_{G_2},[\Psi_1]_1,[\Psi_2]_1,\dots,[\Psi_m]_1)$$
The prover steps are the same as before:
$$\begin{align*}
[A]_1 &= [\alpha]_1 + \sum_{i=1}^m a_iu_i(\tau)\\
[B]_2 &= [\beta]_2 + \sum_{i=1}^m a_iv_i(\tau)\\
[C]_1 &= \sum_{i=\ell+1}^m a_i[\Psi_i]_1 + h(\tau)t(\tau)\\    
\end{align*}$$
And the verifier steps now include pairing by $[\gamma]_2$ and $[\delta]_2$ to cancel out the denominators:
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + [X]_1\bullet [\gamma]_2 + [C]_1\bullet [\delta]_2$$
The thing I’m not understanding :
So it seems to me the description above is the attack is possible because the 2 $G_2$ points resulting from the witness input split for public inputs are equals, if yes why is it required to modify both the private and public terms ? Does it means there’s a way to forge public inputs without knowing the discrete logarithm between $[G]_2$ and  $[\delta]$ ?
Why not just divide the private terms that constitute $[C]_1$ by $[\delta]$ and leave the public terms as is ? I’m meaning having :
$$[A]_1\bullet[B]_2 \stackrel{?}= [\alpha]_1 \bullet [\beta]_2 + [X]_1\bullet [G]_2 + [C]_1\bullet [\delta]_2$$

Of course, other toxic waste are required in a trusted setup, but I’m only focusing on what’s required to prevent public input forgery…
